# Intermittent 'Cannot open database requested by login' error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 box serving a couple .NET websites from IIS 7.5 using SQL Server Express 2008 R2.

The sites have been running for a number of years without issue.  In the last couple of weeks they have become unreliable and will randomly fail with the error "Cannot open database 'foo' requested by the login. The login failed".  They both fail at the same time and once in the broken state they stay broken for all requests.  It's failing roughly once a day.

The credentials and permissions are absolutely correct and have worked for years, work in the management studio and work again when I bounce the server.

I have found that stopping/starting each website in IIS does not resolve the issue, but stopping/starting IIS does.  The leads me to think that something is getting corrupt or badly cached in memory.

Debugging is a pain as the websites need to be fixed ASAP but it's impossible to trace the issue once it's been fixed.

Anybody seen this before or got any idea where I could look for clues next time it goes down?

Comment: Has traffic increased over the years. Could be a memory pressure issue. How much memory does the server have? Have you capped the amount of memory SQL Server reserves?

Comment: I had similar case when a database was starting up or similar.. Or when default database was not specified in user definition. Can you check the errors in SQL Server Error log?